# Linker error building QtWebKit on Win32 with MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

Qt version is qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.1.1

ICU version is icu4c-51_2-Win32-msvc10

> ```
> C:\Qt\qtwebkit>echo %include%
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include;;C:\Qt\icu\include;
> ```

```
C:\Qt\qtwebkit>echo %lib%
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\LIB;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\lib;;C:\Qt\angleproject\lib\Debug;;C:\Qt\icu\lib;;C:\Qt\qtbase\
lib;;C:\Qt\qtwebkit\WebKitBuild\Release\lib;


C:\Qt\qtwebkit>perl Tools\Scripts\build-webkit --qt --debug
```

Seems to compile fine, then linker error...

```
        echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "..\\..\\bin\\jsc.exe.embed.manifest">..\..
\bin\jsc.exe_manifest.rc
        if not exist ..\..\bin\jsc.exe if exist ..\..\bin\jsc.exe.embed.manifest del ..\..\bin\jsc.exe.embed.manifest
        if exist ..\..\bin\jsc.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y ..\..\bin\jsc.exe.embed.manifest ..\..\bin\jsc.exe_manifest.ba
k
        link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.
Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MA
NIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:..\..\bin\jsc.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:..\..\bin\jsc.exe @C:\Users\patrick\AppData\Local\Temp\nm1547
.tmp
   Creating library ..\..\bin\jsc.lib and object ..\..\bin\jsc.exp
JavaScriptCored.lib(JSGlobalObjectFunctions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_charType_51 referenced i
n function "bool __cdecl WTF::Unicode::isSeparatorSpace(int)" (?isSeparatorSpace@Unicode@WTF@@YA_NH@Z)
JavaScriptCored.lib(FunctionPrototype.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _u_charType_51
JavaScriptCored.lib(Lexer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _u_charType_51
JavaScriptCored.lib(DatePrototype.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _udat_close_51 referenced in function
 "class JSC::JSCell * __cdecl JSC::formatLocaleDate(class JSC::ExecState *,class JSC::DateInstance *,double,enum JSC::Lo
caleDateTimeFormat)" (?formatLocaleDate@JSC@@YAPAVJSCell@1@PAVExecState@1@PAVDateInstance@1@NW4LocaleDateTimeFormat@1@@Z
)
JavaScriptCored.lib(DatePrototype.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _udat_format_51 referenced in functio
n "class JSC::JSCell * __cdecl JSC::formatLocaleDate(class JSC::ExecState *,class JSC::DateInstance *,double,enum JSC::L
ocaleDateTimeFormat)" (?formatLocaleDate@JSC@@YAPAVJSCell@1@PAVExecState@1@PAVDateInstance@1@NW4LocaleDateTimeFormat@1@@
Z)
JavaScriptCored.lib(DatePrototype.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _udat_open_51 referenced in function
"class JSC::JSCell * __cdecl JSC::formatLocaleDate(class JSC::ExecState *,class JSC::DateInstance *,double,enum JSC::Loc
aleDateTimeFormat)" (?formatLocaleDate@JSC@@YAPAVJSCell@1@PAVExecState@1@PAVDateInstance@1@NW4LocaleDateTimeFormat@1@@Z)

JavaScriptCored.lib(YarrInterpreter.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_tolower_51 referenced in functio
n "int __cdecl WTF::Unicode::toLower(int)" (?toLower@Unicode@WTF@@YAHH@Z)
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _u_tolower_51
JavaScriptCored.lib(YarrInterpreter.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_toupper_51 referenced in functio
n "int __cdecl WTF::Unicode::toUpper(int)" (?toUpper@Unicode@WTF@@YAHH@Z)
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _u_toupper_51
WTFd.lib(WTFString.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_charDirection_51 referenced in function "enum WTF
::Unicode::Direction __cdecl WTF::Unicode::direction(int)" (?direction@Unicode@WTF@@YA?AW4Direction@12@H@Z)
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _u_charDirection_51
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_strToLower_51 referenced in function "int __cdec
l WTF::Unicode::toLower(wchar_t *,int,wchar_t const *,int,bool *)" (?toLower@Unicode@WTF@@YAHPA_WHPB_WHPA_N@Z)
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_strToUpper_51 referenced in function "int __cdec
l WTF::Unicode::toUpper(wchar_t *,int,wchar_t const *,int,bool *)" (?toUpper@Unicode@WTF@@YAHPA_WHPB_WHPA_N@Z)
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_strFoldCase_51 referenced in function "int __cde
cl WTF::Unicode::foldCase(wchar_t *,int,wchar_t const *,int,bool *)" (?foldCase@Unicode@WTF@@YAHPA_WHPB_WHPA_N@Z)
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_foldCase_51 referenced in function "int __cdecl
WTF::Unicode::foldCase(int)" (?foldCase@Unicode@WTF@@YAHH@Z)
WTFd.lib(StringImpl.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _u_memcasecmp_51 referenced in function "int __cdec
l WTF::Unicode::umemcasecmp(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,int)" (?umemcasecmp@Unicode@WTF@@YAHPB_W0H@Z)
WTFd.lib(CollatorICU.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ucol_strcoll_51 referenced in function "public: e
num WTF::Collator::Result __thiscall WTF::Collator::collate(wchar_t const *,unsigned int,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)co
nst " (?collate@Collator@WTF@@QBE?AW4Result@12@PB_WI0I@Z)
WTFd.lib(CollatorICU.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ucol_setAttribute_51 referenced in function "priv
ate: void __thiscall WTF::Collator::createCollator(void)const " (?createCollator@Collator@WTF@@ABEXXZ)
WTFd.lib(CollatorICU.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ucol_open_51 referenced in function "private: voi
d __thiscall WTF::Collator::createCollator(void)const " (?createCollator@Collator@WTF@@ABEXXZ)
WTFd.lib(CollatorICU.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ucol_getAttribute_51 referenced in function "priv
ate: void __thiscall WTF::Collator::createCollator(void)const " (?createCollator@Collator@WTF@@ABEXXZ)
WTFd.lib(CollatorICU.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ucol_getLocaleByType_51 referenced in function "p
rivate: void __thiscall WTF::Collator::createCollator(void)const " (?createCollator@Collator@WTF@@ABEXXZ)
WTFd.lib(CollatorICU.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ucol_close_51 referenced in function "private: vo
id __thiscall WTF::Collator::releaseCollator(void)" (?releaseCollator@Collator@WTF@@AAEXXZ)
..\..\bin\jsc.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 18 unresolved externals
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'

Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '(' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem. During the linkage of the WTF module, there are a bunch of unresolved external symbols, even if %QTDIR% is set to the correct folder, %QTDIR%/lib is added to the LIB environment variable, have ICU, etc. No success!

Comment: Oh, I used the package downloaded from http://qt-project.org/downloads as the %QTDIR%. My guess is that those libraries are not compiled with ICU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt5 doesn't work with QGIS which was why I wanted it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I solve it on this way:

[How to build Qt5 with OpenSSL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261974/how-to-build-qt5-with-openssl-support)

```
nmake clean
configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -mp -confirm-license -opengl desktop -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32 -llibeay32" -I C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\include -L C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\lib -L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" -l Gdi32 -l User32
nmake
```