# How to build Qt5 with OpenSSL support

Tags: qt, visual-c++, build, openssl, qt5

What is the correct configuration for building Qt5 with SSL support? I have currently compiled OpenSSL statically with VC2008 using the following command lines:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32
ms\do_ms
nmake -f ms\nt.mak 
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
```

Configured Qt 5.3.1 with:

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -mp -confirm-license -opengl desktop -no-icu -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples -platform win32-msvc2008 -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32 -llibeay32" -I C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\include -L C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\lib
```

I get multiple linkage errors like

```
moc_qnetworkreply.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall QSslCertificate::operator==(class QSslCertificate const &)const " (??8QSslCertificate@@QBE_NABV0@@Z)
```

How to get the Qt to compile with OpenSSL support linked? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

OK finally I found that it is quite important to clean the configuration before reconfiguring. In previous versions of Qt `nmake confclean` did the trick but it seems it does not work anymore. According to [QTBUG-34304](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-34304) for now it is usefull to do `git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"` instead of `nmake confclean`. After that a few more tweaks about gdi32.lib and user32.ilb were required to get the following configure line work:

```
configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -mp -confirm-license -opengl desktop -no-icu -skip qtserialport -skip qtwebkit-examples -platform win32-msvc2008 -openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32 -llibeay32" -I C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\include -L C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-32\lib -L "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" -l Gdi32 -l User32
```

then

```
nmake
```

and Voilà.

Comment: Simply build outside of the source tree and you won't ever have this problem again. To "clean" you simply remove the build directory, and create another one. Easy.