# Build QT Source with OpenSSL and MSVC2017

Tags: qt, visual-c++, openssl

I managed to compile openssl-1.0.2o (using nasm-2.13.03) like shown here:
https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_Desktop_for_Windows_with_MSVC

However trying to build the Qt-Source already fails when trying to configure using the following command (it works without ssl/openssl):

```
C:/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/configure -platform win32-msvc2017 -prefix win32-msvc2017 -opensource -confirm-license -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -skip qt3d -I C:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -L C:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -ssl -openssl
```

with the following Error in command line:

```
Note: No wayland-egl support detected. Cross-toolkit compatibility disabled.

ERROR: Feature 'openssl' was enabled, but the pre-condition '!features.securetransport && (features.openssl-linked || libs.openssl_headers)' failed.

ERROR: Feature 'ssl' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'config.winrt || features.securetransport || features.openssl' failed.
```

the config.log reveals it fails because of an "alloca.h"

```
 Command line: -platform win32-msvc2017 -prefix win32-msvc -opensource -confirm-license -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -skip qt3d -I C:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -L C:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -ssl -openssl
loaded result for config test config.qtbase.tests.verifyspec
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\verifyspec && C:\qt_build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" C:/Entwicklung/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/config.tests/verifyspec
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\verifyspec && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   del verifyspec.obj
>   del verifyspec.exp verifyspec.vc.pdb verifyspec.ilk verifyspec.idb
> C:\qt_build\config.tests\verifyspec\verifyspec.exp konnte nicht gefunden werden
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdverifyspec.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\config.tests\verifyspec -I. -IC:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\verifyspec.obj.5420.0.jom
> verifyspec.cpp
>   link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:verifyspec.exe @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\verifyspec.exe.5420.328.jom
test config.qtbase.tests.verifyspec succeeded
loaded result for config test config.qtbase.tests.architecture
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\arch && C:\qt_build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" C:/Entwicklung/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/config.tests/arch
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\arch && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   del arch.obj
>   del arch.exp arch.vc.pdb arch.ilk arch.idb
> C:\qt_build\config.tests\arch\arch.exp konnte nicht gefunden werden
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdarch.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\config.tests\arch -I. -IC:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\arch.obj.12860.0.jom
> arch.cpp
>   link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:arch.exe @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\arch.exe.12860.94.jom
Detected architecture: i386 (sse sse2)
test config.qtbase.tests.architecture gave result i386
loaded result for config test config.qtbase.tests.sse2
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\x86_simd && C:\qt_build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" "CONFIG+=add_cflags" "DEFINES+=NO_ATTRIBUTE" "SIMD=sse2" C:/Entwicklung/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/config.tests/x86_simd
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\x86_simd && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   del main.obj
>   del x86_simd.exp x86_simd.vc.pdb x86_simd.ilk x86_simd.idb
> C:\qt_build\config.tests\x86_simd\x86_simd.exp konnte nicht gefunden werden
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -arch:SSE2 -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdx86_simd.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DNO_ATTRIBUTE -DQT_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_SSE2 -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\config.tests\x86_simd -I. -IC:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.11032.0.jom
> main.cpp
>   link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:x86_simd.exe @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\x86_simd.exe.11032.109.jom
test config.qtbase.tests.sse2 succeeded
loaded result for config test config.qtbase.tests.aesni
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\x86_simd && C:\qt_build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" "CONFIG+=add_cflags" "DEFINES+=NO_ATTRIBUTE" "SIMD=aesni" C:/Entwicklung/qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1/qtbase/config.tests/x86_simd
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\x86_simd && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   del main.obj
>   del x86_simd.exp x86_simd.vc.pdb x86_simd.ilk x86_simd.idb
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -arch:SSE2 -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdx86_simd.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DNO_ATTRIBUTE -DQT_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_AESNI -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\config.tests\x86_simd -I. -IC:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.16356.0.jom
> main.cpp
>   link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:x86_simd.exe @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\x86_simd.exe.16356.93.jom
test config.qtbase.tests.aesni succeeded
loaded result for config test config.qtbase.tests.alloca_h
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\alloca_h && C:\qt_build\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe "CONFIG -= qt debug_and_release app_bundle lib_bundle" "CONFIG += shared warn_off console single_arch" "QMAKE_LIBDIR += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" "INCLUDEPATH += C:\\openssl-1.0.2o\\out32dll" C:/Entwicklung/qt_build/config.tests/alloca_h
+ cd /d C:\qt_build\config.tests\alloca_h && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom clean && set MAKEFLAGS=& jom
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   del main.obj
> C:\qt_build\config.tests\alloca_h\main.obj konnte nicht gefunden werden
>   del alloca_h.exp alloca_h.vc.pdb alloca_h.ilk alloca_h.idb
> C:\qt_build\config.tests\alloca_h\alloca_h.exp konnte nicht gefunden werden
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>   cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zi -MDd -W0 -EHsc /Fdalloca_h.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -I. -IC:\openssl-1.0.2o\out32dll -IC:\qt-everywhere-src-5.11.1\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fo @C:\Users\msrei\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.14548.0.jom
> main.cpp
> main.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht ge”ffnet werden: "alloca.h": No such file or directory
> jom: C:\qt_build\config.tests\alloca_h\Makefile [main.obj] Error 2
test config.qtbase.tests.alloca_h FAILED
```

Comment: You only need OPENSSL_PREFIX=location where you built OpenSSL. Make sure that this location has both lib and include folders. Then add OPENSSL_LIBS=-llib1 -lib2 etc- those are OpenSSL’s dependencies followed by two ssl libraries. Those variable assignments are given to configure on its command line. I’ve been building that release a lot in a CI environment and it’s problem-free with last released VS.

Comment: How would the command look like? Btw i realized that the include folder of openssl is empty. Do i need it? Where do i get them? Or do i just need the compiled stuff in out32dll

Comment: Of course you need the include folder. Build OpenSSL yourself — no biggie. As for the configure command, just put the assignments as arguments. It’s that easy. `configure -foo -bar OPENSSL_PREFIX=C:\Qt\OpenSSL-Win32 ...`

Comment: With this now configure runs through successfully. It will Show OpenSSL=yes but Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no.
Will i be able to use SSL like this? Is there still something wrong with the configuration?

D:/Tools/Qt/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure -platform win32-msvc2017 -prefix win32-msvc2017 -opensource -confirm-license -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -skip qt3d -ssl OPENSSL_PREFIX=D:\Tools\Qt\OpenSSL

Comment: I cant compile it.. it Fails on the qnetwork-module because of openssl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked using openssl 1.0.2 configured like this:

```
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
perl Configure VC-WIN32 --prefix=C:/openssl
nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak
nmake -f ms/ntdll.mak install
```

and this configure:

```
D:/qt-everywhere-src-5.10.0/configure -platform win32-msvc2017 -prefix win32-msvc2017 -opensource -confirm-license -debug-and-release -force-debug-info -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -skip qt3d -ssl -openssl-linked OPENSSL_PREFIX=C:\openssl
```

for using it in a Qt-Project with MSVC2017 add this to your projects .pro file

```
win32-msvc* {
    LIBS += -LC:/openssl/lib/ -llibeay32
    LIBS += -LC:/openssl/lib/ -lssleay32
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/openssl/include
}
```

Comment: Using `-openssl-linked OPENSSL_LIBS="-lssleay32 -llibeay32" -I C:\<opensslpath>\include -L C:\<opensslpath>\lib` as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24271568/1666676) worked better for me than using `OPENSSL_PREFIX` when building `qtbase`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Qt 5.10, but for 5.11.1, the following works - open a CMD prompt and run vcvarsall first, of course.

### build-openssl.bat

```
@set SRC=openssl-1.0.2o
@if "%VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH%"=="x86" (
    @set BITS=32
    @set DST=OpenSSL-Win32
    @set CONFIG=VC-WIN32
    @set SETUP=ms\do_nasm
) else if "%VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH%"=="x64" (
    @set BITS=64
    @set DST=OpenSSL-Win64
    @set CONFIG=VC-WIN64A
    @set SETUP=ms\do_win64a
) else goto no_vscmd
@echo Building %SRC% for %BITS% bits.

@echo - Downloading
@perl ^
    -e "use LWP::Simple;" ^
    -e "mirror('https://www.openssl.org/source/%SRC%.tar.gz', '%SRC%.tar.gz');"

@echo - Decompressing
@if not exist %SRC%.tar.gz goto no_archive
@rmdir /S /Q %SRC% %DST% 2>NUL
@7z x -bsp2 -y %SRC%.tar.gz >NUL && ^
7z x -bsp2 -y %SRC%.tar     >NUL && ^
del %SRC%.tar
@if errorlevel 1 goto unpack_failed
@if not exist %SRC% goto no_source

@echo - Building
@pushd %SRC%
@perl Configure %CONFIG% --prefix=%~dp0..\%DST% && ^
call %SETUP% && ^
nmake -f ms\nt.mak init && ^
jom -f ms\nt.mak "CC=cl /FS" && ^
jom -f ms\nt.mak test && ^
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install || goto build_failed
@popd
@rmdir /S /Q %SRC%

@echo Build has succeeded.
@goto :eof

:no_archive
@echo Error: can't find %SRC%.tar.gz - the download has failed :(
@exit /b 1

:unpack_failed
@echo Error: unpacking has failed.
@exit /b %errorlevel%

:no_source
@echo Error: can't find %SRC%\
@exit /b 1

:build_failed
@echo The build had failed.
@popd
@exit /b 2

:no_vscmd
@echo Use vcvars-32 or vcvars-64 to set up the Visual Studio
@echo build environment first.
@exit /b 100
```

Then, to build Qt 5.11.1, I use the following configuration:

```
-opensource
-confirm-license
-force-debug-info
-debug-and-release
-ltcg
-openssl
-qt-zlib
-qt-libpng
-qt-libjpeg
-plugin-sql-sqlite
-mp
OPENSSL_PREFIX="c:\foo\OpenSSL-Win32"
-nomake examples
-make-tool jom
-platform win32-msvc
-opengl dynamic
-no-iconv
-no-dbus
```

Where `foo` is whatever folder you happened to run `build-openssl.bat` in.

Ensure that you have jom in the path, otherwise you'll hate the whole process. The latest jom is at: http://download.qt.io/official_releases/jom/jom.zip

The script to add all the tools into your path (so that you don't have to set it globally):

### toolpaths.bat

```
@set V_7ZIP=%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip
@set V_PERL64=C:\Perl64
@set V_PERL32=C:\Perl
@set V_PYTHON27=C:\Python27
@set V_NASM=%ProgramFiles%\NASM
@set V_NASM32=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\NASM
@set V_SMARTGIT32=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\SmartGit
@set V_SMARTGIT=%ProgramFiles%\SmartGit
@set V_CMAKE=%ProgramFiles%\CMake
@set V_CMAKE32=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\CMake
@set V_VS2015=2015
@set V_VS2015COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%
@set V_VS2017COMNTOOLS=%VS150COMNTOOLS%

@if not exist "%V_7ZIP%\7z.exe" goto no_7zip
@call :append_path "%V_7ZIP%"
@goto has_7zip
:no_7zip
@echo Warning: 7-Zip not installed. OpenSSL will not build.
:has_7zip

@if not exist "%V_PERL64%\bin" goto no_perl64
@if not exist "%V_PERL64%\site\bin" goto no_perl_site64
@call :append_path "%V_PERL64%\site\bin"
:no_perl_site64
@call :append_path "%V_PERL64%\bin"
@goto has_perl
:no_perl64

@if not exist "%V_PERL32%\bin" goto no_perl
@if not exist "%V_PERL32%\site\bin" goto no_perl_site32
@call :append_path "%V_PERL32%\site\bin"
:no_perl_site32
@call :append_path "%V_PERL32%\bin"
@goto has_perl
:no_perl
@echo Warning: Perl not installed. Qt will not build.
:has_perl

@if not exist "%V_PYTHON27%" goto no_python
@call :append_path "%V_PYTHON27%"
@goto has_python
:no_python
@echo Warning: Python 2.7 not installed. Qt will not build.
:has_python

:check_nasm
@if not exist "%V_NASM%\nasm.exe" goto check_nasm32
@call :append_path "%V_NASM%"
@goto has_nasm
:check_nasm32
@if not exist "%V_NASM32%\nasm.exe" goto no_nasm
@call :append_path "%V_NASM32%"
@goto has_nasm
:no_nasm
@echo Warning: NASM not installed. OpenSSL will not build.
:has_nasm

:check_git
@if not exist "%V_SMARTGIT%\git\bin" goto check_git32
@call :append_path "%V_SMARTGIT%\git\bin"
@goto has_git
:check_git32
@if not exist "%V_SMARTGIT32%\git\bin" goto no_git
@call :append_path "%V_SMARTGIT32%\git\bin"
@goto has_git
:no_git
@echo Warning: SmartGit not installed. Qt WebEngine might not build.
:has_git

:check_cmake
@if not exist "%V_CMAKE%\bin\cmake.exe" goto check_cmake32
@call :append_path "%V_CMAKE%\bin"
@goto has_cmake
:check_cmake32
@if not exist "%V_CMAKE32%\bin\cmake.exe" goto no_cmake
@call :append_path "%V_CMAKE32%\bin"
@goto has_cmake
:no_cmake
@echo Info: CMake not installed. This is without consequences.
:has_cmake

:: configure gyp overrides for msvs 2017 express
@if not exist "%VS150COMNTOOLS%\VsDevCmd.bat" goto no_vs2017gyp
@call :set_path V_VS2017 "%VS150COMNTOOLS%\..\.."
@echo Info: Found MSVS 2017 at "%V_VS2017%"
@set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2017
@set GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=%V_VS2017%
@goto no_vs2015gyp
:no_vs2017gyp

:: configure gyp overrides for msvs 2015 express
@if not exist "%VS140COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\WDExpress.exe" goto no_vs2015gyp
@call :set_path V_VS2015 "%VS140COMNTOOLS%\..\.."
@echo Info: Found MSVS Express 2015 at "%V_VS2015%"
@set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2015
@set GYP_MSVS_OVERRIDE_PATH=%V_VS2015%
:no_vs2015gyp

@exit /b

:append_path
@echo %PATH%|find "%~1">nul || PATH %PATH%;%~1
@goto :eof

:set_path
@set %1=%~f2
@goto :eof
```

Comment: Very nice script. May I ask how I can tweak it to compile OpenSSL in debug?

Comment: No idea :/ I have since written a proper gnu makefile to build OpenSSL on Windows – a single makefile, that is, that handles all the dependencies. I have to post it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done today to solve this particular problem and build Qt 5.11.1 shared libraries with OpenSSL and MySQL support:

- Download **OpenSSL 1.0.2L** [precompiled binaries from npcglib.org](https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-openssl/), make sure to choose the version suited for your specific MS compiler ([VS 2017](https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/downloads/openssl-1.0.2l-vs2017.7z));
- Install **MySQL Connector/C v6.1.6** (v6.1.11 is more recent, but I haven't tried it);

After extracting the OpenSSL package to `c:\openssl`, the following commands ran successfully:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\openssl\ssl\openssl.cnf

configure -shared -debug-and-release -opensource -confirm-license -sql-mysql -opengl dynamic -platform win32-msvc2017 -prefix C:\Qt\qt5.11.1-msvc2017-shared -nomake tests -nomake examples -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\include" -L "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector.C 6.1\lib" -ssl -openssl -I "C:\openssl\include" -L "C:\openssl\lib"

nmake

nmake install
```

I recommend building Qt sources from the Github repository, simply because if things go wrong and you need to clean the build directory, `nmake clean` is super super slow. To properly clean the building directory and do it fast when building from the git repository, you can get rid of all temporary files with:

```
rm config.cache
git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"
```

And your system should be ready to execute another `configure`.